Can I decode the transfers (SOL and SPL) from the simulate transaction logs?
I want to decode the transfers that will take place in a transaction by decoding the transaction logs.
Is it possible to do so?
[
  'Program ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL invoke [1]',
  'Program log: Create',
  'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [2]',
  'Program log: Instruction: GetAccountDataSize',
  'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 1569 of 394633 compute units',
  'Program return: TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA pQAAAAAAAAA=',
  'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA success',
  'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [2]',
  'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success',
  'Program log: Initialize the associated token account',
  'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [2]',
  'Program log: Instruction: InitializeImmutableOwner',
  'Program log: Please upgrade to SPL Token 2022 for immutable owner support',
  'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 1405 of 388046 compute units',
  'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA success',
  'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [2]',
  'Program log: Instruction: InitializeAccount3',
  'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 4188 of 384164 compute units',
  'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA success',
  'Program ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL consumed 20307 of 400000 compute units',
  'Program ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL success',
  'Program 6EF8rrecthR5Dkzon8Nwu78hRvfCKubJ14M5uBEwF6P invoke [1]',
  'Program log: Instruction: Buy',
  'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [2]',
  'Program log: Instruction: Transfer',
  'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 4645 of 358211 compute units',
  'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA success',
  'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [2]',
  'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success',
  'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [2]',
  'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success',
  'Program 6EF8rrecthR5Dkzon8Nwu78hRvfCKubJ14M5uBEwF6P invoke [2]',
  'Program 6EF8rrecthR5Dkzon8Nwu78hRvfCKubJ14M5uBEwF6P consumed 2003 of 346123 compute units',
  'Program 6EF8rrecthR5Dkzon8Nwu78hRvfCKubJ14M5uBEwF6P success',
  'Program data: vdt/007mYe6xKZvoPG2coG1qZxOgSruyKhh8+d/Az5TqQMSO3tDQGiIAAAAAAAAApFMSAAAAAAABzUug7TUEWp9Y2+YA4xjJpeeu0n3YsXw2MPvYT23+yTFf1NFmAAAAAAgeWf0GAAAAJPFWgzrPAwAIcjUBAAAAACRZRDep0AIA',
  'Program 6EF8rrecthR5Dkzon8Nwu78hRvfCKubJ14M5uBEwF6P consumed 37298 of 379693 compute units',
  'Program 6EF8rrecthR5Dkzon8Nwu78hRvfCKubJ14M5uBEwF6P success'
]

For example these are the logs of a successful simulate transaction. I want to know the transfers that happened in this simulation.

The logs won't give the information of the transfer amounts, but they will tell you if a transfer happened. If you see:
'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke' // some trailing [x] here
'Program log: Instruction: Transfer'

Then it's sure there was a transfer. If you want to know the amounts though, you'll need to deserialize the account state after the simulation.

This is possible.
You'll need to fetch the transaction details, here's how I do it using UMI, but the flow should be similar using web3.js
    const txHash = ""; // input your transaction signature here

    const res = await umi.rpc.getTransaction(base58.serialize(txHash), {
        commitment: "finalized",
    });

    console.log(res?.meta);

The details you are looking for will be inside the meta object where you can find preBalances and postBalances for native SOL and preTokenBalances and postTokenBalances for SPL token accounts.
sample output for tx hash hgwMP6erwJfhuzYfT8AfP8kn1S2J1WkY5cR5usoQkEZMaJfg6iD4UnH4rTSzqdfabw6mGPXvt9BBmkchwtEy34e would look like
{
  fee: { basisPoints: 5000n, identifier: 'SOL', decimals: 9 },
  logs: [
    'Program 4mFDYND4AVREYEJXCPhjq1LnbjELHHebJqG3NZechA7X invoke [1]',
    'Program log: Instruction: MakeBid',
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [2]',
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success',
    'Program ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL invoke [2]',
    'Program log: Create',
    'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [3]',
    'Program log: Instruction: GetAccountDataSize',
    'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 1595 of 171602 compute units',
    'Program return: TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA pQAAAAAAAAA=',
    'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA success',
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [3]',
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success',
    'Program log: Initialize the associated token account',
    'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [3]',
    'Program log: Instruction: InitializeImmutableOwner',
    'Program log: Please upgrade to SPL Token 2022 for immutable owner support',
    'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 1405 of 164989 compute units',
    'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA success',
    'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [3]',
    'Program log: Instruction: InitializeAccount3',
    'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 4214 of 161105 compute units',
    'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA success',
    'Program ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL consumed 21990 of 178577 compute units',
    'Program ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL success',
    'Program EA4ptgF3TYjDBGYJApAoZoyCbCYw6P5mGU5noCe1Z97 invoke [2]',
    'Program log: Instruction: DepositToken',
    'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [3]',
    'Program log: Instruction: TransferChecked',
    'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 6173 of 131592 compute units',
    'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA success',
    'Program EA4ptgF3TYjDBGYJApAoZoyCbCYw6P5mGU5noCe1Z97 consumed 20529 of 145268 compute units',
    'Program EA4ptgF3TYjDBGYJApAoZoyCbCYw6P5mGU5noCe1Z97 success',
    'Program 4mFDYND4AVREYEJXCPhjq1LnbjELHHebJqG3NZechA7X consumed 76372 of 200000 compute units',
    'Program 4mFDYND4AVREYEJXCPhjq1LnbjELHHebJqG3NZechA7X success'
  ],
  preBalances: [
    { basisPoints: 13832974576n, identifier: 'SOL', decimals: 9 },
    { basisPoints: 2575200n, identifier: 'SOL', decimals: 9 },
    { basisPoints: 2039280n, identifier: 'SOL', decimals: 9 },
    { basisPoints: 3594960n, identifier: 'SOL', decimals: 9 },
    { basisPoints: 2982081040n, identifier: 'SOL', decimals: 9 },
    { basisPoints: 1461600n, identifier: 'SOL', decimals: 9 },
    { basisPoints: 0n, identifier: 'SOL', decimals: 9 },
    { basisPoints: 0n, identifier: 'SOL', decimals: 9 },
    { basisPoints: 1n, identifier: 'SOL', decimals: 9 },
    { basisPoints: 1141440n, identifier: 'SOL', decimals: 9 },
    { basisPoints: 731913600n, identifier: 'SOL', decimals: 9 },
    { basisPoints: 1141440n, identifier: 'SOL', decimals: 9 },
    { basisPoints: 934087680n, identifier: 'SOL', decimals: 9 }
  ],
  postBalances: [
    { basisPoints: 13828751816n, identifier: 'SOL', decimals: 9 },
    { basisPoints: 2575200n, identifier: 'SOL', decimals: 9 },
    { basisPoints: 2039280n, identifier: 'SOL', decimals: 9 },
    { basisPoints: 3594960n, identifier: 'SOL', decimals: 9 },
    { basisPoints: 2982081040n, identifier: 'SOL', decimals: 9 },
    { basisPoints: 1461600n, identifier: 'SOL', decimals: 9 },
    { basisPoints: 2039280n, identifier: 'SOL', decimals: 9 },
    { basisPoints: 2178480n, identifier: 'SOL', decimals: 9 },
    { basisPoints: 1n, identifier: 'SOL', decimals: 9 },
    { basisPoints: 1141440n, identifier: 'SOL', decimals: 9 },
    { basisPoints: 731913600n, identifier: 'SOL', decimals: 9 },
    { basisPoints: 1141440n, identifier: 'SOL', decimals: 9 },
    { basisPoints: 934087680n, identifier: 'SOL', decimals: 9 }
  ],
  preTokenBalances: [
    {
      accountIndex: 2,
      amount: [Object],
      mint: 'BpBqiAoNFYVZr8vr3V5CHFX3HkRwnihNcKnzvxAEZ38e',
      owner: 'J63YroB8AwjDVjKuxjcYFKypVM3aBeQrfrVmNBxfmThB'
    }
  ],
  postTokenBalances: [
    {
      accountIndex: 2,
      amount: [Object],
      mint: 'BpBqiAoNFYVZr8vr3V5CHFX3HkRwnihNcKnzvxAEZ38e',
      owner: 'J63YroB8AwjDVjKuxjcYFKypVM3aBeQrfrVmNBxfmThB'
    },
    {
      accountIndex: 6,
      amount: [Object],
      mint: 'BpBqiAoNFYVZr8vr3V5CHFX3HkRwnihNcKnzvxAEZ38e',
      owner: '8RD1QDumWCGq5Q2FKzz6Hj1RrRP31ce2XF5udNuZW2NF'
    }
  ],
  innerInstructions: [ { index: 0, instructions: [Array] } ],
  loadedAddresses: { writable: [], readonly: [] },
  computeUnitsConsumed: 76372n,
  err: null
}


I think I confused somewhere in the original question.
I want to know the changes that will occur in the transaction before the transaction actually takes place using simulateTransaction.

I think you should make a new question for that. I think it should be possible to use simulateTransaction method

Yes I did edit the question.
